# How can I make my LaTeX text look like Knuth's CWEB text?

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, letterspacing

I think this font is `cmr`, but what about the spacing?

[image: knuth and levy's cweb]

Comment: Welcome! What about the spacing? Where is the image from? What have you tried?

Comment: I do not think the above is a good example to follow actually. First of all, too many words on one line. It is best to keep number of words between 9-12 or so. Also, I think having a little bit of vertical space between paragraphs helps readability as well. IMHO of course. Are you sure that Knuth wrote the above?

Comment: @Nasser it was written by Donald Knuth or Silvio Levy (joint authors) try `texdoc cweb`

Comment: it's just default setting in computer modern, what features are you looking for? The tex source is https://ctan.org/tex-archive/web/c_cpp/cweb/cwebman.tex you have tagged this as letterspacing but there is no letterspacing in this example as far as I can see.

Comment: Expanding on @DavidCarlisle's comment, the "style" used for this documentation is defined in `cwebmac,tex`, based on `plain.tex`, and the text width is 6.5 inches.  This is definitely wider than recommended for easy reading, but is frequently used for technical documentation (in the U.S,) because of its economical use of paper.  But other than that, there's nothing special about the spacing.